# Torque setting range, set to high end?

Tags: hyundai, torque-specification, range

I replaced the front struts and pads and rotors on a Hyundai Accent a couple months back. I used [This Manual](http://www.hamanual.com/replacement-859.html) for the correct torque settings. I am not used to a range torque as I have worked on Chevy's with Haynes manuals where generally a single torque values is given. Not thinking too much about it, I used the max torque value for each bolt to torque everything down. I also used blue loctite on all of the fasteners (minus the lugs for the wheels) as well, for added safety. Doing some reading, some recommend setting the torque value a bit below the max range.

I had checked my torque wrench for accuracy when I did the work by hanging a 20lb weight off of it 15 inches back with the torque value of 25lbs ((15/12) × 20) = 25. Clicked.. moved setting up a tad, and it wouldn't click. Also, I always store at lowest setting too. So it seems the torque wrench isn't way off or anything.

I've put over 1,000 miles on the car since doing the work throughout the summer, from short trips on bumpy construction roads, to long trips on the expressway.

I came across a Youtube video that mentioned the torque value range, and they were setting it more mid range, between the two bounds. So this got me thinking, and I took a look at the manual and realized the ranged value. Putting more thought into it, I am wondering if there are any risks putting it at the high end of the range as a diy job.

First, do I need to worry about having the torque value at the high range? I would think engineers aren't going to put the torque value just below the bolt's shear point.. but I don't want to assume anything in this case.

Having done the work on a hot summer day, will cold weather create a hazard in anyway with the torque setting at the higher range? And I mean worse case.. Like the Vortex we had in the Midwest a couple years ago that had temps lower than -20 deg (without the wind chill).

I also want to note that this is the torque value for the wheel: "65.1 ~ 79.6lb-ft"  My tire shop (Discount Tires) gives me a print out when I rotate the tires. And they have their torque settings on the lug nuts listed at 80lbs. Looks like they're going a little above the max.

Comment: Why not test a spare bolt in a vice and see how much above the torque setting you have to go to shear it. You might be surprised...

Comment: I don't have a vice nore a spare Hyundai bolt at the moment :)  do you have a specific example in mind you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your diatribe, you've torqued your wheel lugs and suspension bolts to the top end of what the manual stated you should torque them to. If this is what you did, quit worrying about it. You have done *exactly* what you needed to do for safe operation. Lug nuts will stand up to far in excess of what the rated torque in the book is given. You can take a look at what I'd bet is well over 50% of the tire shops in the US do to know this is true. What do they do? They do two things wrong. First the tighten the crap out of the lug nuts (well beyond manufacturer's specs - even when attempting to use a torque wrench ... because they have no clue how to use it correctly) and secondly they don't torque them equally. In most cases you will strip a lug nut on the lug before you'll shear it. If a lug does happen to shear, it usually happens when taking the nut off rather than putting them on (due to the threads being seized).

This applies to all the other bolts you've tightened as well. I don't think I would have used Loctite on them, but that shouldn't make too much of a difference.

Seriously, don't worry about it. You've done what you were supposed to do. Drive the car. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! I get worried since I don't know the behind the scenes data, and hate to assume anything with my wife driving my 1yr old around. I also came across some information about loctite changing the torque value and needed to be compensated with 15% difference.. But then I remembered I used permatex, and a quick look at their technical data sheet, "https://www.permatex.com/wp-content/uploads/tech_docs/tds/24250.pdf"  mentions, "No torque compensation required during assembly"  Phew!   But it's nice to hear it from someone with your reputation and experience, that there is no need to worry.